# How to add inline Styles in Java Mail without breaking a line

Tags: html, css, styles, jakarta-mail

I want to add inline following inline style for a given text inside a java mail.if i add like this output as follows.

```
<p>Please check the attachement to download the promotion letter with the password of your </p>" +"<b>"+ "NIC No + Birth Year (Example : 786083518 "+" <p style=\"color:red;\">1978)</p>" +"</b>"
```

[image]

What i want is 1978 in red ) black in the same row.

Comment: Have you tried to use `div` or `span` instead of `p`aragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you have:

```html
<p>Please check the attachement to download the promotion letter with the password of your </p><b>NIC No + Birth Year (Example : 786083518 <p style="color:red;">1978)</p></b>
```

Instead you can use the following:

```html
<p>Please check the attachement to download the promotion letter with the password of your <b>NIC No + Birth Year (Example : 786083518 <span style="color:red;">1978)</span></b></p>
```